# Create hrefs in knockout JS grids

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to have a table with KO bindings. By following the example in this tutorial, http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html, I have made a grid this variable.

```
var PagedGridModel = function(items) {
this.items = ko.observableArray(items);

this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
    data: this.items,
    columns: [
        { headerText: "Date Created", rowText: function (response) { 
                                                    var d = new Date(response.postingDate);
                                                    return d.toLocaleDateString(); 
                                                } },

        { headerText: "Subject", rowText: "subject" },

        { headerText: "Status", rowText: "status" },

        { headerText: "Date Updated", rowText: function (response) { 
                                                    var d = new Date(response.updationDate);
                                                    return d.toLocaleDateString(); 
                                                } },

        { headerText: "", rowText: function (response) {  } }
    ],
    pageSize: 10
});
};
```

I need to write a function in the last rowText to create a hyperlink for my page. This is the JSP that I'm trying to replace with Knockout.

```
<c:forEach items="${responses}" var="response">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${response.postingDate}</td>
                                    <td>${response.subject}</td>
                                    <td>${response.status}</td>
                                    <td>${response.updationDate}</td>
                                    <c:url value="/contact/viewDetails" var="viewDetailsURL">
                                    <c:param name="ticketId" value="${response.ticketID}"/>
                                    </c:url>
                                    <td><a href="${viewDetailsURL}">View Details</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                </c:forEach>
```

How do I create a href for "View Details" in the last rowText function?

Comment: See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [attr binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) like this

```
<a data-bind="attr:{href: '${viewDetailsURL}'}">View Details</a>
```